# Explanation needed on what situations make a task run on two hosts in the same try?

Tags: ansible

I came across a task that seems to be trying to run on two hosts like so:

```
TASK [setup] *******************************************************************
fatal: [====]: UNREACHABLE! => {"changed": false, "msg": "ssl: auth method ssl requires a password", "unreachable": true}
ok: [web-app.source-ami]
```

Of course, I am trying to debug that error and figure out where `====` came from.

But this is also the first time I have come across a task trying to run on multiple hosts like this in one and the same try.

```
TASK [setup] *******************************************************************
Using module file /usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/ansible/modules/core/windows/setup.ps1
<====> ESTABLISH WINRM CONNECTION FOR USER: Administrator on PORT 5986 TO ====
fatal: [====]: UNREACHABLE! => {
    "changed": false, 
    "msg": "ssl: auth method ssl requires a password", 
    "unreachable": true
}
Using module file /usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/ansible/modules/core/system/setup.py
<web-app.source-ami> ESTABLISH LOCAL CONNECTION FOR USER: ec2-user
<web-app.source-ami> EXEC /bin/sh -c '( umask 77 && mkdir -p "` echo $HOME/.ansible/tmp/ansible-tmp-1536934067.19-26447522223236 `" && echo ansible-tmp-1536934067.19-26447522223236="` echo $HOME/.ansible/tmp/ansible-tmp-1536934067.19-26447522223236 `" ) && sleep 0'
<web-app.source-ami> PUT /tmp/tmpFfmjhW TO /home/ec2-user/.ansible/tmp/ansible-tmp-1536934067.19-26447522223236/setup.py
<web-app.source-ami> EXEC /bin/sh -c 'chmod u+x /home/ec2-user/.ansible/tmp/ansible-tmp-1536934067.19-26447522223236/ /home/ec2-user/.ansible/tmp/ansible-tmp-1536934067.19-26447522223236/setup.py && sleep 0'
<web-app.source-ami> EXEC /bin/sh -c '/usr/bin/python /home/ec2-user/.ansible/tmp/ansible-tmp-1536934067.19-26447522223236/setup.py; rm -rf "/home/ec2-user/.ansible/tmp/ansible-tmp-1536934067.19-26447522223236/" > /dev/null 2>&1 && sleep 0'
ok: [web-app.source-ami]
```

PLAYBOOK starts like this:

```
---

- name: Fetch AMI ID
  hosts: base-source-amis:&{{ subset | default('None') }}
  connection: local
  tags: [ ami-id ]

  roles:
    - { role: do_something }
```

COMMAND:

```
ansible-playbook -i ../../hosts_file \
            -e subset=ami-bakes-resources \
            playbook
```

I have looked at the inventory and it seems to be straight-forward and has no mention of `====` anywhere.

Hosts_file:

```
localhost ansible_connection=local

[base-resources]
web-app.ec2
web-app.source-ami

[base-source-amis]
web-app.source-ami

[ami-bakes-resources:children]
base-resources
```

Host Vars:

```
# host_vars/web-app.source-ami
---
aws_resource_id: ami-34549s3d
...
```

No group vars for groups at present.

I also searched for `winrm` and it is used for connection to windows instances elsewhere but here the task is using `connection: local` when running on a linux machine.

```
# group_vars/windows-instances/settings.yml
---

ansible_connection: winrm
ansible_ssh_port: 5986
ansible_ssh_user: Administrator

...
```

Comment: Where did you specify your hosts? Your inventory file. Look at that.

Comment: I did. It doesnt mention anything about ==== so I wondered maybe figure out under what conditions can this 2 host in one test try thing happen. Thanks for helping.

Comment: Are you doing some kind of dynamic inventory, then? Please explain all the details of how you got to this point.

Comment: Michael, I have added more info now after experimenting further. Still struggling to solve this though :(